# Visual Studio 2017 se cuelga

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Cuando intento programar una app en xamarin.forms en visual studio 2017 community edition, se cuelga el IDE, debugando devenv.exe en otra instancia de visual studio recibo el siguiente error:

> No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir. 
>   El subproceso 0x544 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
>   Excepción producida en 0x76BCC54F (KernelBase.dll) en devenv.exe:
>   0xE0434352 (parámetros: 0x80131622, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
>   0x00000000, 0x71990000).

Finalmente termina por cerrar-se visual studio con esta otra excepción:

> Excepción producida en 0x6F4A114D (System.ni.dll) en devenv.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al leer la ubicación 0x00000000.
>
> Si hay un controlador para esta excepción, el programa puede continuar
>   de forma segura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**¿Causas del problema?**

Puede que sean muchas, pero las más comunes són problemas de ficheros si hemos tenido una versión anterior de `visual studio`, conflictos entre librerías instaladas de diferentes versiones del programa o instancias de ejecución de las librerías entre versiones distintas de `visual studio`.

**¿Cómo lo he solucionado?**

Limpiando completamente las versiones anteriores de `visual studio` y haciendo una reinstalación completa de `visual studio 2017`.

Hemos de asegurarnos que nuestro proyecto puede trabajar con las librerías que va a instalar `visual studio 2017`, y preocupar-nos de que estén instaladas.